# How do I change the language (specifically from french to english) in Visual Studio 2008's compiler output

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, localization

At first I had the french version of VS, then I installed the English version on top of it; so now I have the menus in English, but the compiler still outputs in French.

Changing the language in 'Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings' doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet:

[Example of how to use Visual Studio IDE language switching](https://web.archive.org/web/20151206062356/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2006/03/24/560579.aspx)

EDIT: from comment by astebner on 31 Jan 2008 1:49 PM (page linked above)

> Compiler messages come from the .NET
> Framework, so they are controlled by
> your OS language settings and whether
> or not you have any .NET Framework
> language packs installed.  To make the
> compiler messages change to English,
> you would need to change your OS
> language preferences to English or
> uninstall the .NET Framework German/**French**
> language pack from your system.

Comment: Thanks, I removed all .NET application mentioning FR (via the control panel). And also the French version of visual studio. And it worked.